# Search potentially multiple params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, search

I'm wanting to search by possibly 2 params, but both don't need to be present either. Right now, the state_id passes as "" if nothing is selected, and I don't know how to get rid of that.

View:

```
<div dropdown-toggle>
 <%= form_tag('/municipalities', method: :get) do %>
 <%= select_tag(options_for_select(@dropdown), {:allow_blank => "Please select"}, class: "btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle")  %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", class: "btn btn-default"
 %>
  <%= link_to "Reset", municipalities_path, class: "btn btn-default" %>
  <%= button_tag 'Counties Only', name: "municipality_type", value: "County", class: "btn btn-default pull-right" %>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

Controller (I'm still new, so this is not as clean as it could be)

```
 def index

  @dropdown = State.all.map{ |s| [s.state, s.id]}
  @municipality = Municipality.order(:name)
  @count = @municipality.count

  if !params[:state_id].to_s.blank? && params[:municipality_type].present?
        @municipalities = Municipality.where(municipality_type: params[:municipality_type], state_id: params[:state_id])
        @forms = Form.where(municipality_id: @municipalities, state_id: @state)
        if !params[:state_id].blank?
          @present = params[:state_id] 
          @state = params[:state_id]
          @state_name = State.find(@state)
        end
        @count_state = @municipalities.count
  elsif params[:state_id].present?
    @present = params[:state_id] 
    @state = params[:state_id]
    @state_name = State.find(@state)
    @municipalities = Municipality.where(state_id: @state)
    @forms = Form.where(municipality_id: @municipalities)
    @count_state = @municipalities.count
  else
    @forms = nil
    @state = State.all
    @municipalities = Municipality.order(:name)
  end
end
```

Comment: Which model are you trying to search?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, you can just make your conditions simply `if params[:state_id] && params[:municipality_type]` and `elsif params[:state_id]` respectively and they will pass the condition if submitted in the form.

Comment: My issue is that if no state is chosen, it still passes a param[:state_id] = ""  I need it to pass nothing, or nil, if there hasn't been a state chosen, so it only searches counties.

Comment: Sorry I totally misunderstood. I think you should do as Ben has suggested below then because if you want a blank option in the drop down and it is selected, it will always pass an empty string.

Comment: Another option might be to remove the button_tag from the form and make it a button_to then it should not submit the rest of the paramaters from the form i.e. the state_id

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a shot, I might not be interpreting your intent correctly. You seem to be defining a lot of variables that you don't need.

I believe this is all you need to get municipalities searched by two params, but allow them to be blank:

```
def index
  @municipailies = Municipality.order(:name)
  state_id = params[:state_id]
  type = params[:municipality_type]
  @municipalities = Municipality.where(state_id: state_id) if state_id
  @municipalities = Municipality.where(municipality_type: type) if type
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! The issue isn't in the controller (I don't think), it's in the view. My issue is that if no state is chosen, it still passes a param[:state_id] = ""  I need it to pass nothing, or nil, if there hasn't been a state chosen, so it only searches counties.

Comment: Okay, then change the if statement to `if state_id.present?`

Comment: Yes, I don't think I'm explaining myself correctly. With if state_id.present? it evaluates to true, because the state_id is being passed as "". And even though it's not a number, it's still evaluating to a present value.

Comment: `"".present?` should be evaluating to false. Is it possible you are actually getting the param[:state_id] from somewhere else not in you view code above? You are not actually setting the state_id in the select tag based on whet you post above - it should be more like `<%= select_tag("state_id", options_for_select(@dropdown), {:include_blank => true, class: "btn btn-default btn-lg dropdown-toggle"})  %>`. Note I have also changed the class to be inside the bracket of options. I have not tested this BTW...